# How to connect to remote repo?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I'm using libgit2sharp and i'm having rouble connecting to my remote repo.

I can connect to a local repo but when i try to use my repo https://github.com/myProject/myRepo i get an error

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: failed to make directory './https:': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Presumably this is because i'm not using the correct syntax. I've tried without https://, with www. i've tried just myProject/myRepo but they don't seem to work.

Here is the code in question. PathToRepo is the repo path and whenever i check the branches of my repo after it is created i ee that it is not connecting to the remote repo. The repo seems to create with no issues but it just doesn't sync to my repo. Ie. i could put in some bogus repo path and it will create with no problem but just not work.

```
 if (!Repository.IsValid(PathToRepo))
            {
                Repository.Init(PathToRepo);
            }

            repo = new Repository((PathToRepo));
            var brnch = repo.Branches.Where(x => x.FriendlyName == Branch).FirstOrDefault();
            if (brnch == null)
            {
                brnch = repo.CreateBranch(Branch);
            }
            Commands.Checkout(repo, brnch);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to connect

Comment: edited. I'm just using new Repository(PathToRepo) to create the repo

Comment: Your code looks okay, it's the configuration that's going to be the problem.  How did you clone this repository?  Did you update the git remote manually or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you might want to try using the .git URL instead. So try something like `https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git` instead of `https://github.com/torvalds/linux`

Comment: I throws an error whenever i use an https:// address. I feel like the syntax is off.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source of `LibGit2Sharp.Repository` class that you are using:
https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs

The constructor says the `String path` parameter is to a directory. I don't see any suggestion that this works with a web address, so I suspect that the constructor you are using only works with local repositories in a local directory.

After a quick search through that same source file, I found `ListRemoteReferences` which might list references for your remote repo, and `Clone` which will likely clone a remote repo. (I haven't tried either of these myself).